# Django cannot login (login view does not return set-cookie header for sessionid at login)

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-2.2

I am getting the following response from the Django (2.2) default login view:

```
Request URL: https://api.n.exchange/en/accounts/login/?next=/en/referrals/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 104.25.23.99:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
CF-RAY: 51105b439e71b50e-VNO
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: br
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2019 13:37:09 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Expires: Wed, 04 Sep 2019 13:37:09 GMT
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=BHfEypgp6ux4FvQr14G06DQnqHjRL0tXZYP4Cg2b67naaFkxFw29g0C5UVettETb; expires=Wed, 02 Sep 2020 13:37:09 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Cookie, Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-NewRelic-App-Data: PxQGUlFVCwoGR1JTDwQFX1IAFB9AMQYAZBBZDEtZV0ZaCldOdxRdARBfWA9JB1JSXgMOTFReWRIWWFQdAxMXCh4UUQdPSw5+XAJQD2cIVhVKUVIVRE8IHwBKUVAPBw5QVggOBltfUVYDUw5WFBUFHhFVAFAABABbAQEGWFYGWQVSRk0EVl1EAzk=
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,he;q=0.7,lt;q=0.6,de;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __cfduid=d76f7b7d2a1caa6948456ad6829dc25991553698344; _ga=GA1.2.2123122031.1553698346; _ym_uid=1553698347983819119; _ym_d=1553698347; crisp-client%2Fsession%2F6eb9ed9e-2c8b-48e8-a0ce-62c3ce81fb61=session_76921095-b26c-4790-a968-82cf111e3940; _hjid=e834477e-35c2-4ef9-aacd-5fb2d644ae2c; crisp-client%2Fsocket%2F6eb9ed9e-2c8b-48e8-a0ce-62c3ce81fb61=1; _gid=GA1.2.1927749960.1567447617; USER_TZ=Europe/Vilnius; django_language=en; _ym_isad=1; _ym_visorc_42222484=w; _ym_visorc_45642111=w; csrftoken=BHfEypgp6ux4FvQr14G06DQnqHjRL0tXZYP4Cg2b67naaFkxFw29g0C5UVettETb; _gat=1
Host: api.n.exchange
Referer: https://api.n.exchange/en/accounts/login/?next=/en/referrals/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
X-NewRelic-ID: VQUAV1VaDhADVVlXBQgBVw==
next: /en/referrals/
```

As you can clearly see, the `set-cookie` header for the `sessionid` which represents the authenticated Django session is missing.

What could be the cause? (at first, I was thinking the reason is that we have a self signed HTTP certificate behind Cloudflare but we have migrated to a valid letsencrypt certificate and removed cloudflare to test it, but the problem persists).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN was set to the wrong setting